# Edit multiple cells to hyperlink without doing one by one

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a spreadsheet that has a column that contains text that is hyperlink. The hyperlink is not active until I perform edit. I can use "F2" then "ENTER" which activates hyperlink, however have to do one cell at a time. I believe this could be done with either VBA or Macro but not sure of wording

Tried recording macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should turn the text in the cell into a hyperlink

```
Sub HyperCellCreate()

For icell = 1 To 10
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(icell, 1).Select
    HyperString = CStr(Cells(icell, 1).Value)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=HyperString,TextToDisplay:=HyperString
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, please be kind and leave feedback :)

Comment: You don't need to `Select` the cell, and you *should always* declare your variables properly :)